# sudo as user permission denied on command

Tags: permissions, sudo, cd-command

Hi i'm having a real problem trying to run a script as root, the script is to use sudo to run wp-cli as the user required.

The command I am using is

`sudo -u hstestsite1 -s "cd /home/hstestsite1/public_html; /usr/local/bin/wp plugin list"`

I receive

`/bin/bash: cd /home/hstestsite1/public_html; /usr/local/bin/wp plugin list: Permission denied`

However if I su to that user and run the command it all works fine

```
su - hstestsite1
cd /home/hstestsite1/public_html; /usr/local/bin/wp plugin list
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| name    | status   | update | version |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| akismet | inactive | none   | 3.3.3   |
| hello   | inactive | none   | 1.6     |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
```

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: is your script trying to exeute the entire command `"cd /home/hstestsite1/public_html; /usr/local/bin/wp plugin list"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sudo doesn't handle multi-line commands in its shells, but you can create a shell inside of your sudo command and have that shell run multiple commands, like so:

```
sudo -u hstestsite1 -s sh -c "cd /home/hstestsite1/public_html; /usr/local/bin/wp plugin list"
```